# Focus Select element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to programatically focus a select element in Material-UI in a useEffect block.

Trying to pass a ref to the component (`ref={my ref}`) itself does nothing, and trying to pass any variety of `inputProps={{ ref: myRef }}`, `inputProps={{ inputRef: myRef }}` [throws an error](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/52b80a0b29fe37184bcf1ab1c88bee40958fd197/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L79) for displayNode being undefined when I call focus() on the ref.

I am sure there is something obvious I am missing, what would be the correct syntax/way to do this?

```
const MyCard = ({
  disabled,
}) => {
  const inputField = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!disabled && inputField.current) {
      inputField.current.focus();
    }
  }, [inputField, disabled]);

  return (
    <Select
      disabled={disabled}
      inputProps={{ ref: inputField }}
      required
      id="answer"
      name="answer"
      autoComplete='off'
      autoFocus
    >
      <MenuItem value="option1">option1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="option2">option2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Additional info from OP:

> I need to be able to programmatically focus the select. Autofocus
>   works for me on the initial render, but not subsequently, specifically
>   I am trying to refocus the input after removing the disabled prop.

Comment: Where do call `.focus()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check that it is defined before calling `focus`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (myRef.current) {
    myRef.current.focus()
  }
}, [myRef])
```

Comment: It is defined, it is here that is raising: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/52b80a0b29fe37184bcf1ab1c88bee40958fd197/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L79

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue recently, and it works after add a setTimeout. Most likely the input is a child component of select, and it is rendered after its parent finish rendering.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!disabled && inputField.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {inputField.current.focus()}, 0);
    }
}, [inputField, disabled]);
```